# Changing states but controller is not being called in angular js

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, controller, state

I have a webpage which displays the user profile information from the database which is working fine, and another one in which user edits his/her information, which is edited in the database, which is also working. 
But after I change the data in the second webpage, I have changed the state to the first page using `$state.go`, which also seems to be working, but the newly updated data is not showing in this first page, the controller is not being called I think.

This is my controller of webpage which shows the userprofile :
`.controller('myProfileCtrl', function (..parameters..) {
        $scope.id = window.localStorage.getItem("profileId");
            $scope.$root.loading = true;
            $http.get('my link...')
                .success(function (data) {
                    $scope.first_name = data[0].first_name;
                    $scope.middle_name = data[0].middle_name;
                 })`

This is the controller of my second page which updates the user information :
     `.controller('editPersonalCtrl', function (..parameters..) {
        $scope.saveChanges = function (user) {
      $http.post('my link..', {
                changeFirstName : new_first_name,
                changeMiddleName : new_middle_name,
            })
                .success(function (data) {
                $state.go('profile');//Go to the first webpage
                    $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
                        disableBack: true,
                        historyRoot: true
                    });
                })
                .error(function (data) {
                    alert("ERROR" + data);
                });
          }`

The state changes but the newly updated data is not shown, I mean the controller of the first webpage is not working, otherwise it would have fetched the new data from the database and displayed it. The old data is showing.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
$state.go('profile');
```

with

```
$state.go('profile', {}, { reload: true });
```

It will force the to transit and than also it's not working you can do like

```
$state.go('profile', {}, {reload: true,notify: true});
```

This will force and also will broadcast $stateChangeStart and $stateChangeSuccess events. Here is the [ref](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state)

Comment: Have you tried disabling cache in chrome or cleared cache if using any other browser ?

Comment: Try this in case you don't have fixed version         $state.transitionTo('profile', {}, { reload: true, inherit: false, notify: true }); It was a fix https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/582